# How do I make this run

Tags: java

How do I make this run:

```java
package mychoices;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MyChoices {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
        Scanner ls = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("What's your name?");
        String next = in.next();
        char userName = (char)System.in.read();
        
        System.out.println("Do you like rock music?");
        System.out.println("Enter Y for yes or N for no");
        char userChoice = (char) System.in.read();
        String Y = ls.next();
            
        if(Y.equals('Y')) {   
            System.out.println("Recomendations");
        }               
        System.out.println("Thanks for visiting, " + (ls));            
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do. What are the inputs, what are the expected outputs, and what are the outputs that you get? Are there exceptions? Then you should paste the stack traces into the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try below code.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyChoices {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ls = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What's your name?");
        String userName = in.nextLine(); //Get user name

        System.out.println("Do you like rock music?");
        System.out.println("Enter Y for yes or N for no");
        char userChoice = in.next().charAt(0);

        if(userChoice=='Y'){
            System.out.println("Recommendations");
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for visiting, " + userName);

    }
}
```

[Refer screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQkk0.jpg)

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019 Community edition IDE [Free edition].

You can click on buttons highlighted in red color to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use two Scanners that are both reading from System.in.

You cannot cast a String to a char with:
 `char userName = (char)System.in.read();`

delete that line, since it seems you do not use `userName` anywhere.

Same mistake here: `char userChoice = (char)System.in.read();`
Replace that with `char userChoice = in.read().charAt(0);`

Now that you have a character, replace    `if(Y.equals('Y')){`  
with `if (userChoice == 'Y') {`